# DataFrameGroupBy diff() on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose i have a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CATEGORY':['a','b','c','b','b','a','b'],
                   'VALUE':[pd.np.NaN,1,0,0,5,0,4]})
```

which looks like

```
    CATEGORY    VALUE
0      a         NaN
1      b         1
2      c         0
3      b         0
4      b         5
5      a         0
6      b         4
```

I group it:

```
df = df.groupby(by='CATEGORY')
```

And now, let me show, what i want with the help of example on one group 'b':

```
df.get_group('b')
```

group b:

```
    CATEGORY    VALUE
1      b          1
3      b          0
4      b          5
6      b          4
```

**I need**: In the scope of each group, count diff() between `VALUE` values, skipping all `NaN`s and `0`s. So the result should be:

```
    CATEGORY    VALUE  DIFF
1      b          1      - 
3      b          0      -
4      b          5      4
6      b          4     -1
```

Comment: Yes, pandas has vectorized `.diff()`. NaNs in your series are a pain, so it's best to `fillna()`/`dropna()` them on your dataframe before doing anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) to subtract values after dropping `0` and `NaN` values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CATEGORY':['a','b','c','b','b','a','b'],
               'VALUE':[pd.np.NaN,1,0,0,5,0,4]})

grouped = df.groupby("CATEGORY")

# define diff func
diff = lambda x: x["VALUE"].replace(0, np.NaN).dropna().diff()
df["DIFF"] = grouped.apply(diff).reset_index(0, drop=True)

print(df)

  CATEGORY  VALUE  DIFF
0        a    NaN   NaN
1        b    1.0   NaN
2        c    0.0   NaN
3        b    0.0   NaN
4        b    5.0   4.0
5        a    0.0   NaN
6        b    4.0  -1.0
```

Comment: Actually, this doesnt work for groups.  Error comes up, because you cant `replace` the DataFrameGroupBy. I have rewrited it this way:`.apply(lambda x: np.NaN if x==0)` but this didnt help;(

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav Updated the answer for your `groupby`.

Comment: In python3 it ends with  `'DataFrameGroupBy' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav Are you sure? The above example works fine in Python 3 with pandas 19.2. Actually, there is no item assignment to a `DataFrameGroupBy` object in the above code. Try to run the example in a clean environment.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for a `pd.Series.shift()` operation along with a `notnull` mask.

First we remove the unwanted values, before we group the data

```
nonull_df = df[(df['VALUE'] != 0) & df['VALUE'].notnull()]
groups = nonull_df.groupby(by='CATEGORY')
```

Now we can shift internally in the groups and calculate the diff

```
nonull_df['next_value'] = groups['VALUE'].shift(1)
nonull_df['diff'] = nonull_df['VALUE'] - nonull_df['next_value']
```

Lastly and optionally you can copy the data back to the original dataframe

```
df.loc[nonull_df.index] = nonull_df

df
  CATEGORY  VALUE  next_value  diff
0        a    NaN         NaN   NaN
1        b    1.0         NaN   NaN
2        c    0.0         NaN   NaN
3        b    0.0         1.0  -1.0
4        b    5.0         1.0   4.0
5        a    0.0         NaN   NaN
6        b    4.0         5.0  -1.0
```